# Timezone for timestamp in logs?

Tags: php, datetime, symfony, timezone, monolog

I have correctly set the timezone for PHP. But the timestamps in the Symfony2 logs (Monolog) do not reflect that.

- Is it hardcoded to UTC+0 or something?
- Is that the best practice for logs?
- How can I change this?

Comment: How did you set the timezone ? U set it in php.ini or with date_default_timezone_set() Function ? If u set it with a function its clear that the symfony2 system is preseting the timezone (or using the default from .ini file). So the best would be to set it from php.ini , not at runetime .

Comment: @TudorTudor I used cli/php.ini and fpm/php.ini

Comment: I'm not used to symfony , but in my opinion it must be a problem with the timestamp synchronisation somewhere . Try to use echo date_default_timezone_get() in different spots of the symfony system to see when the timezone changes ...

Comment: P.S. for the comment above(can't edit) timezone synchronization not timestamp .

Answer (score -1):

There are at least 2 ways to cause PHP to behave as if it was in the timezone of your choice.

1. Follow this other FAQ to [change timezone for your entire account.](http://support.modwest.com/content/20/257/en/how-do-i-change-the-timezone-for-my-account.html)
2. If you only want particular PHP scripts (and not shell or other cgi scripts) to use a specific timezone, set the timezone environmental variable in your PHP code like so:

   echo "Original Time: ". date("h:i:s")."\n";

   putenv("TZ=US/Eastern");

   echo "New Time: ". date("h:i:s")."\n";

If you put the line `putenv("TZ=US/Eastern");` in a file that is 
include()'ed by all your other PHP scripts, then all your PHP scripts will use that timezone.

A list of timezones to choose from, other than "US/Eastern" for your putenv() is here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_time_zones

Comment: My time/timezone is fine, this is a specific issue with Symfony2's logs.